# how to convert a bsondocument into a strongly typed object without bson deserializer in monogodb using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch class object('let it be myObj') with built in **find'<'myObj'>'(Filter)** function in C#
But it returns only bsonDocument

Note:
my key and value pair will be dynamic for the filter

my Code:
List'<'myObj'>' obj = collection.Find(BuilderFilter.Eq("key", "value")).Skip(skipValue).Limit(limitValue).ToList();

doc reference for the find function:
https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm

Comment: Please add your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding a document based on a query from MongoDB with C# driver,

```
myObj record = collection.Find(Builders<myObj>.Filter.Eq(x => x.property, valueToLookup)).FirstOrDefault();
```

where collection is of type `IMongoCollection`.

Comment: no it is not working
getting Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent<myObj, MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'myObj'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: can you say what you tried and what didnt work? Provide the code that is relevant and provides enough information to show how it should work but doesnt. Got the error.. what was the actual code you tried?

Comment: Please update your question above to include the code you tried that didnt work.

Comment: List<myObj> obj = collection.Find(Builder<myObj>Filter.Eq("key", "value")).Skip(skipValue).Limit(limitValue).ToList();

Comment: @BalajiArun Try it this way, `List<myObj> obj = collection.Find(Builder<myObj>Filter.Eq(x => x.key, "value")).Skip(skipValue).Limit(limitValue).ToList();`

Comment: but my key and values will be dynamic